# Error saying process.send is not a function when using npm `workerpool`

Tags: node.js, process, git-diff

I am using `workerpool` npm package and creating a dedicated worker to calculate git diff of two files ([git-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-diff))
When I try to run this using npm run script I am getting `process.send is not a function` error

We use `temporal` workflows and thought that running this as part of a wf might be the reason for this but temporal has nothing to do with it
[image]

Comment: [Do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5781499)

Comment: Did u resolve this?